# linear differential equation without solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know this differential equation does not have any solution but how can I prove it?

$\begin{cases} 
      x'=f(x)  \\
      x(0)=0
   \end{cases}$

where $f(x)=\begin{cases} 
        0 &x>0    \\
      1 &  x\le  0
   \end{cases}$

what happens if $x(0)\neq 0$? Thanks to everyone

Comment: Have you heard of Darboux's theorem?

Comment: @Ian unfortunately never, is this the only way?

Comment: That's the easiest way that I can think of, unless you have a regularity requirement built into the definition of "solution".

Comment: @Ian I was reading Darboux's theorem , is it right to say f is discontinouos with a jump at x=0 so it does not have solution? But when x(0)<0 or x(0)>0 i solve only 1 case of the system ?

Comment: Basically the point is that $x'$ must have a jump if $x(0)=0$: it is supposed to be $1$ at $t=0$ and then somehow immediately become $0$, which is impossible. If $x(0)<0$ then there is no problem initially but you'll hit $x=0$ eventually.

Comment: @Ian really thanks for the solution and all details. If you want you can post one of your comments as answer and i'll give you as accepted ( I don't know if I can thank you in this way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to prove that the problem in the OP has no solution even local in time is to use Darboux's theorem, which states that a function that is the derivative of another function has the intermediate value property. The equation would imply that $x'(0)=1$, but then by the definition of $f$, $x'$ would need to immediately become zero. A problem with that (not the only one, actually) is that it contradicts Darboux's theorem.

For $x(0) \neq 0$ you encounter the same problem at $t=-x(0)$.